# How to append a list using values from other list(maximum in the first must be minimum in the second)

Tags: list, python-2.7, max

```
a = [1 5 2 4 6 3]
```

I have this list. Is there a way to make a second corresponding list with the same number but 6 from `a list` must be 1 in the `b list` and 1 in `a list` must be 6 in `b list` .I want exactly this:

```
b = [6 2 5 3 1 4]
```

Comment: @DeepSpace ok lets say we have numbers 1-10 randomly in a list i want 10 to be 1 in the second list and 1 to be 10. Then 9 from the first list shall be 2, 8 shall be 3 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` of the sorted, and reversed-sorted list to create a reverse mapping from reversed-tuples:

```
>>> a = [1, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3]
>>> reverse_mapping = dict(zip(sorted(a), reversed(sorted(a))))
```

Creates the following mapping:

```
{1: 6, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 1}
```

Now use that to construct the new list:

```
>>> b = [reverse_mapping[item] for item in a]
>>> b
[6, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4]
```

This can be optimized if needed, I just kept it clear.

Comment: exactly what i wanted! can u please explain a bit more the steps?

Comment: What part exactly?

Comment: reverse_mapping = dict(zip(sorted(a), reversed(sorted(a))))     and    b = [reverse_mapping[item] for item in a]

Comment: Sure. It creates a sorted list and a reverse-sorted list (inner expressions), and the zips them together and creates a mapping from these tuples which is the translation you're after.

Comment: Thank you...you've been more than helpful :)